# Nginx Rewrite subfolder to a sub domain and keep everything after it

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the url to handle the following scenario, I want to redirect a few specific subfolders to a few specific subdomains and keep whatever was after the sub folder.

So far I have:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/sub1/?(.*)$ https://sub1.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub2/?(.*)$ https://sub2.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub3/?(.*)$ https://sub3.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub4/?(.*)$ https://sub4.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This handles `example.com/sub1` `example.com/sub1/` `example.com/sub1/foobar`
But not `example.com/sub1/page.php` this goes to `example.com/sub1/page.php` and 404's cause it doesn't exist.

I want
`example.com/sub1` to go to `sub1.example.com`
`example.com/sub1/` to go to `sub1.example.com/`
`example.com/sub1/foobar` to go to `sub1.example.com/foobar`
`example.com/sub1/foo/bar/` to go to `sub1.example.com/foo/bar/`
`example.com/sub1/page.php` to go to `sub1.example.com/page.php`

What am I missing here? Is my regex that rusty?

EDIT:  Here is my entire config for that site, in case its an issue with something else overriding it. https://pastebin.com/sEka1Q0e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your `server` blocks, you have a `location ~ \.php` block alongside the `location` block containing the `rewrite statements. That regular expression`location`block takes precedence when evaluating URIs which end with`.php`.

One option is to move the rewrite statements into the `server` block, in which case they will be executed **before** any `location` block chosen. For example:

```
server {
    ...

    rewrite ^/sub1/?(.*)$ https://sub1.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub2/?(.*)$ https://sub2.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub3/?(.*)$ https://sub3.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/sub4/?(.*)$ https://sub4.example.com/$1 permanent;

    location / {
    }

    location ~ \.php$ 
    { 
        ... 
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, a more efficient solution would be to place the rewrite statements inside individual prefix locations, but use the `^~` modifier to give them a higher precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

```
location ^~ /sub1 {
    rewrite ^/sub1/?(.*)$ https://sub1.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
location ^~ /sub2 {
    rewrite ^/sub2/?(.*)$ https://sub2.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
location ^~ /sub3 {
    rewrite ^/sub3/?(.*)$ https://sub3.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
location ^~ /sub4 {
    rewrite ^/sub4/?(.*)$ https://sub4.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: But this one is more like a redirect only, I feel. Also, the URL  displayed is https://sub1.example.com/ but what should I do to display the URL as https://example.com/sub1 but serve the content from that virtual host setup sub1.example.com

Comment: @indianwebdevil search for "reverse proxy" and the `proxy_pass` directive.